# how to delete a single node in linked list c++

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

*Edited: My problem is that I did not handle the special case in which the value to delete is the head of the LinkedList. Someone fix it in the answer section.

I have a class of Node, and a function to delete a node in which the value of String matches with any node.

```
class Node
    {
    public:
        string getName() const
        {
           return name;
        }
        Node* getLink() const
        {
           return link;
        }
    private:
        string name;
        Node* link;
    };
typedef Node* NodePtr;

void deleteOneNode(NodePtr& head, string valueToDelete)
{
    NodePtr currentPtr = head, previousPtr = head;
    while (currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->getName() != valueToDelete)
    {
        previousPtr = currentPtr;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->getLink();
    }
    if (currentPtr != NULL)
    {
        previousPtr->setLink(currentPtr->getLink());
        delete currentPtr; **afer this code run, the entire linked list is deleted**
    }
}
```

I only want to delete a single node, not the entire linked list. When I debug the linked list, I noticed that the entire linked list is deleted at some point.
I do not know what did I do wrong?

Comment: *afer this code run, the entire linked list is deleted* how you know that?

Comment: @appleapple I debug the program and figure it out on that point.

Comment: @ laughing just a note, next time post the code that trigger the behavior i.e. [mcve] so others can help you easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work as expected, but you must handle a special case for the case the deleted node is the head :

```
#include <iostream>

class Node
    {
    public:
        Node(std::string  n) {
            name = n;
        }
        std::string getName() const
        {
           return name;
        }
        Node* getLink() const
        {
           return link;
        }
        void setLink(Node *node)
        {
           link = node;
        }
    private:
        std::string name;
        Node* link;
    };
typedef Node* NodePtr;

void deleteOneNode(NodePtr& head, std::string valueToDelete)
{
    //Special case
    if (valueToDelete == head->getName()) {
        head = head->getLink(); 
        return;
     }

    NodePtr currentPtr = head, previousPtr = head;
    while (currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->getName() != valueToDelete)
    {
        previousPtr = currentPtr;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->getLink();
    }
    if (currentPtr != NULL)
    {
        previousPtr->setLink(currentPtr->getLink());
        delete currentPtr; //afer this code run, the entire linked list is deleted**
    }
}

int main()
{
     Node * node1 = new Node("A");
     Node * node2 = new Node("B");
     Node * node3 = new Node("C");
     node1->setLink(node2);
     node2->setLink(node3);

    deleteOneNode(node1, "B");
    std::cout << node1->getLink()->getName() << "\n"; //==> "C"

    deleteOneNode(node1, "A");
    std::cout << node1->getName() << "\n"; //==> "C"
    
    return 0;                          
}
```

Comment: bro, you are right. I bumped my head for a whole night. you saved me. Thank you so much